# AnimationListener functions(Eg: onAnimationEnd) not working for Fragment Transition Animations

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have an activity with 2 fragments. I have added custom animations for fragment transactions using **setCustomAnimations** function. Now I want to perform some operations after **fragment transition animation effect**. For that I implemented **android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener** interface in my main Activity. But **onAnimationEnd** method is not getting invoked after the fragment transition operation. Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set an AnimationListener on these animations because they are provided using a resource identifier. To set an AnimationListener you need a reference to the animation in code and be able to call setAnimationListener to actually set your AnimationListener on a given animation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup your animation in code using one of the following (depending on whether you are using the compatibility library or not):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateAnimator(int, boolean, int)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onCreateAnimation(int, boolean, int)